# decoding ed25519 PublicKey fails with no explanation

Tags: rust, openssl

I am trying to decode a PublicKey in Rust and it fails if I use a byte slice or a PEM encoded key. The example docs merely show it decoding what it encoded, but I generated these keys from openssl. Here is the code I am using:

```rust
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, stdin};
use libp2p::identity::ed25519::{PublicKey};

fn main() {
    BufReader::new(stdin()).lines()
        .map(|l| l.unwrap())
        .for_each(|l| {
            match PublicKey::decode(hex::decode(l).unwrap().as_slice()) {
                Ok(_pk) => println!("pk decoded"),
                Err(e) => println!("{}", e.to_string())
            }
        });
}
```

output:

```
302A300506032B6570032100EDBF0FC3EA90291E030EA95C3D9617C347056FA3126089A3960791C601BF9A72
Key decoding error: Ed25519 public key
```

I generated the keys using openssl as such:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.2/bin/openssl genpkey -algorithm Ed25519 -out ed25519key.pem

/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.2/bin/openssl pkey -in ed25519key.pem -pubout
```

Which gives a public key of:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEA7b8Pw+qQKR4DDqlcPZYXw0cFb6MSYImjlgeRxgG/mnI=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I've tried passing this raw pem as well as the decoded bytes too:

```
302A300506032B6570032100EDBF0FC3EA90291E030EA95C3D9617C347056FA3126089A3960791C601BF9A72
```

Comment: I thought: oh, easy one, the output of openssl is pem encoded, so you need to decode that with [pem::parse](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b088b6401c262e0929bc560fe4df0b1). But it turns out that `pem::parse` also doesn't [do](https://docs.rs/pem/0.6.1/src/pem/lib.rs.html#192) anything other than base64 decoding the content…

Comment: `openssl` generates the private keys with PKCS#8 v1 formatting. I wonder if that library wants v2.

Comment: Taking the output from OpenSSL and throwing it blindly into some other library is playing with fire. Even if it works, you gotta be super-careful and make sure the mathematical representation is the same. This is an easy way to produce vulnerabilities and bugs, and in the cryptocurrency context, lose money. At least create tests that ensure that the points on the curve are the same or something.

Answer (score 4):

[`libp2p::identity::ed25519::PublicKey`](https://docs.rs/libp2p/0.44.0/libp2p/identity/ed25519/struct.PublicKey.html) is just a wrapper around [`ed25519_dalek::PublicKey`](https://docs.rs/ed25519-dalek/1.0.1/ed25519_dalek/struct.PublicKey.html), and when you call [`decode()`](https://docs.rs/libp2p/0.44.0/libp2p/identity/ed25519/struct.PublicKey.html#method.decode), it simply calls [`ed25519_dalek::PublicKey::from_bytes()`](https://docs.rs/ed25519-dalek/1.0.1/ed25519_dalek/struct.PublicKey.html#method.from_bytes) and returns the struct containing the result.

The reason it is failing is because `from_bytes()` expects a raw public key, which is 32 bytes; however, the output from `openssl` isn't a raw key, but rather it is [apparently](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2018-March/007777.html) a 12 byte ASN.1 header followed by the 32 byte raw key. So to get the actual raw key you need to discard the first 12 bytes. You can either do that in your Rust code, or do it up front when you generate the key.

To get only the (base64 encoded) 32 byte key from `openssl`, you can use the following command:

```sh
openssl pkey -in ed25519key.pem -pubout -outform DER | tail -c +13 | openssl base64
```

Comment: That's identical to [this post](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2018-March/007777.html). I need to try it to verify